# .Net framework 4.5.1 Nuget issue with MassTransit

Tags: masstransit

When I try to install MassTransit via Nuget in a .Net Framework 4.5.1 Asp.Net Web application, the following error gets displayed:

```
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : Could not install package 'MassTransit 3.3.5'. You are trying to install this package into a project that 
targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are 
compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
```

Has anyone had the same problem and know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[.NET 4.5.1 is unsupported](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2015/12/09/support-ending-for-the-net-framework-4-4-5-and-4-5-1/) and MassTransit does not support it any longer. Upgrade to v4.5.2+.